# When you make a reference = another reference and both values are null?

Tags: java, null

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList a=null, b=null;
        a=b;

        a=new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(a+""+b);
    }
```

Why in the world b is printed as null ?

I thought java makes references the same then whatever you change in one of them reflects the other. But not in this case !!!

Comment: `a=new ArrayList();`. Were you expecting something else?

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
a = b;
```

Sets the value of `a` to the current value of `b`. That's *all* it does. The current value of `b` is null, so it's equivalent to:

```
a = null;
```

It does *not* associate the two variables. It just copies the value of one to another.

Changing the value of `a` afterwards does *not* change `b` at all. The two variables are entirely separate. Note that this is exactly the same for primitive types:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a = 5;
System.out.println(b); // Prints 10, not 5
```

Even if you had:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArragList<String> b = a;
a.add("Hello");
System.out.println(b.get(0)); // Prints "Hello"
```

That's *still* not really showing a relationship between the variables `a` and `b`. They have the same value, so they refer to the same object (the `ArrayList` itself) - changes to that object can be observed via either variable. But changing the *value* of each variable to refer to a different list (or null) won't affect either the other variable or the object itself.

One thing which may be confusing you is what the value of `a` or `b` actually is. The value of a variable (or any other expression) in Java is never an object - it's always either a *reference* or a primitive value.

So an assignment operator, or passing an argument to a method, or anything like that will never copy the object - it will only ever copy the value of the expression (a reference or a primitive value).

Once you understand this, Java starts to make a lot more sense...

Comment: I do know all of what you said. Thank you. I never knew that null is considered a value (not an object) to references. Thus it makes sense now. Thank you for you detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Variables like your `a` and `b` are called references. They refer to objects. The objects are floating around somewhere else (they are not stored "inside" the variables). When you say `a=b` you make `a` refer to whatever `b` refers to. In your case that makes no difference, because both already refer to `null` (i.e. to no object at all).

When you assign a new object to `a` that makes no difference to what `b` refers to.

Comment: I think it's worth distinguishing between a variable and a value - the variable itself isn't a reference; its *value* is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've redefined a.  When you say:

```
a=new ArrayList();
```

You break the existing relationship between a and b.

Comment: There *is* no relationship between `a` and `b`. They have the same value due to the assignment, that's all. As soon as the assignment operator for `a = b` has completed, the fact that they happen to have the same value is almost coincidental - neither variable has any particular knowledge of the other.

Comment: If you instantiate a as a new ArrayList, then set b to a, and then you add an item to a, and then you call b.get(0), you will get the value you put in a.  Both are referring to the same instance of ArrayList.  Here, when they are set to null, both point at null.  It may not be the correct term to say "relationship" but they both point at the same thing.  When you later say "a=" you point that reference at another instance, or at null.  Now the two references no longer point at the same thing.

Comment: Yes, they're referring to the same instance because they have the same value - but that's not a relationship between the two variables, it's just that they have the same value. And no, assigning a new value to `a` doesn't "point that reference at another instance" - it changes the value of `a` to be a different reference. `a` is a variable, not a reference. It's worth being precise in terminology for this sort of thing.

Comment: a is a reference not a value, if you want to be precise in terminology.  And I already said "relationship" is not the correct term, that horse needs no further beating.

Comment: No, `a` is a variable. It's got a name and a storage location. The *value* of that variable is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put. The variables refers to the object the other variable refers to in the moment it is set and not to the variable itself.

```
ArrayList a=null, b=null; // Both *a* and *b* refers to null
a=b;                      // Set *a* to refer to what *b* refers to (in this case null)
a=new ArrayList();        // Set *a* to refer to a new arraylist. *b* still refers to null.
```